# Socket.io res doesn't get on unity

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, unity-game-engine

I was use Socket.io client on Asset Store.(https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/kr/#!/content/21721)

When I was change scene, socket response is does't work.

for example

Scene A has socketIOComponent prefeb.
code is here. (It is remove 'emit code' and 'socket.on("res",function())' )

```
GameObject go;
public SocketIOComponent socket;

private static Network _instance;

public static Network instance{
    get{
        if(_instance == null){
            _instance = new Network();
        }

        return _instance;
    }
}

void Start () {
    go = GameObject.Find("SocketIO");
    socket = go.GetComponent<SocketIOComponent> ();

    DontDestroyOnLoad (this);
}

void Awake(){
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this);
    } else {
        if(this != _instance){
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

It is implement singleton pattern.

Scene B code is here.

```
Network net;
SocketIOComponent socket;
void Start () {
    net = Network.instance;
    socket = net.GetComponent<Network> ().socket;

    socket.On ("res2", testing);
}

void OnGUI(){
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (200, 200, 50, 50), "Scene 2")) {
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
        js.AddField("Test","test");
        socket.Emit("test2",js);
    }
}

void testing(SocketIOEvent e){
    Debug.Log("12345");
}
```

Node.js server is get request "test2" in 'OnGUI' function.
But 'res2' response is doesn't work.

Server code is here

```
socket.on("test2", function(data){
       socket.emit("res2");
 });
```

. I don't understand this situation. because Scene A is work very well both(req, res) and Scene B is just work Request.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I have just found the solution.

It's necessary to add DontDestroyOnLoad on the instance of SocketIOComponent in the function Awake.

The function Awake must be like that (this is my function Awake) :

```
public void Awake ()
{
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = this;
    } else if (instance != this)
    {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad (socketIO);
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
}
```